# Z3 C API Changing Timeout at Runtime

Tags: z3

Is it possible to change the timeout value of the solver at runtime using C API?
In order to set the timeout the following can be done -

```
Z3_config  cfg = Z3_mk_config();
Z3_set_param_value(cfg, "SOFT_TIMEOUT", "10000") // set timeout to 10 seconds
Z3_context ctx = Z3_mk_context(cfg);
....
Z3_check_and_get_model(ctx);
....
....
Z3_check_and_get_model(ctx);
```

However, suppose we want to change the timeout for next query while retaining the context, is it possible to change the timeout value in between?

Comment: I just came across this API to change the mutable parameter.
`void Z3_API Z3_update_param_value (__in Z3_context c, __in Z3_string param_id, __in Z3_string param_value)`

I dont know if soft_timeout is mutable or not?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider moving to Z3 4.0. Z3 4.0 has new API that allows the user to create many solvers in the same Z3_context. You can set different timeouts for each solver, and update them whenever you want. Z3 4.0 also comes with a C++ layer that makes the C API much more convenient to use.
Here is an short example that sets a timeout. On my machine, Z3 will return `unknown` when the 1 millisecond timeout is used, and `sat` when the `s.set(p)` command is removed.

```
context c;
expr x = c.real_const("x");
expr y = c.real_const("y");
solver s(c);

s.add(x >= 1);
s.add(y < x + 3);

params p(c);
p.set(":timeout", static_cast<unsigned>(1)); // in milliseconds
s.set(p);

std::cout << s.check() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Dear Leonardo, Thanks for quick answers ! I have one more question. I am doing pareto exploration using Z3. I need to assert constraints like in above example (x>=2) and then check for sat 
again assert (x>= 3) and then check for sat and repeatedly so on... 
so what I do is I push the context on the stack before asserting any constraint. When I am done with current query, I pop the context from stack and push it again. So I am ready for next query. Is it best way to do it?

Comment: The constraint `x >= 3` subsumes `x >= 2`. So, you don't need to use `push/pop`. We use `push/pop` when we want to remove constraints. For example, we may want to do it because the current set of assertions is already unsatisfiable.

Comment: Hi @Leonardo, I have a related question. Suppose, in the above example I add assertion (x==y) to solver and want to check with a "different" timeout (say 0.5). Is it possible to do that by calling s.set(p) again? I tried doing it for my client and z3 started giving wrong answers. Maybe setting params again for a solver messes up the internal data structure.