# Z3 JAVA-API for solver timeout

Tags: timeout, z3, java

How to set solver's timeout for Z3 JAVA API?

Back to this question again:

Here is my code:

```
    Context ctx = getZ3Context();
    solver = ctx.MkSolver();
    Params p = ctx.MkParams();
    p.Add("timeout", 1);
    solver.setParameters(p);
```

Not work, the solver just running the query forever. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the Java API, but from Looking at the official [Java example](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8bfbdf1e680d#examples/java/JavaExample.java) and at [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833925/z3-c-api-changing-timeout-at-runtime), I'd assume that something along the following lines should work:

```
Solver s = ctx.MkSolver();
Params p = ctx.MkParams();
p.Add("timeout", valueInMilliseconds); /* "SOFT_TIMEOUT" or ":timeout"? */
s.setParameters(p);
```

Comment: Tried. Weird result. When value < 3000, works; otherwise, the solver doesn't stop.

Comment: Could you tell us what platform you're running this on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally found a solution myself:

```
Context ctx = getZ3Context();
solver = ctx.MkSolver();
Params p = ctx.MkParams();
/* Also tried
 * p.Add("timeout", 1),
 * p.Add(":timeout", 1), 
 * neither worked.
 */
p.Add("soft_timeout", 1);
solver.setParameters(p);
```