# Warnings when using z3 .NET bindings on Linux ("unknown parameter 'model_completion'")

Tags: .net, linux, f#, z3

I compiled the .NET bindings of yesterday's z3 unstable branch under Linux (surprisingly, this works without too much pain) and am now trying to use them in an F# project. This also works, but when executing it, I get many repetitions of the following lines on stderr:

> WARNING: Error setting SOFT_TIMEOUT: unknown parameter 'soft_timeout'
>
> WARNING: Error setting MODEL_COMPLETITION: unknown parameter 'model_completition'

This only happens with our project, not when running the examples/dotnet/Program.cs example. I have no idea where to start looking for the source of this problem. Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried compiling/using the stable branch to see if you get a similar error? Unless there's a new feature you *need* in the unstable branch, you're probably better off using the stable branch instead. Also, have you tried porting the `examples/dotnet/Program.cs` to F#? If you do that, and it works as expected, then that would be a good indicator that the error is somewhere in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples in `examples/dotnet/Program.cs` don't use `soft_timeout` and `model_completion`; why should they print out such warnings?

It seems that you tried to set these parameters on `Context` directly.

In Z3 4.x, you can create multiple solvers from a context so `soft_timeout` should be solver-specific.

```
// Dispose Z3 Context after current scope
use context = Context()
let solver = context.MkSolver()
let p = context.MkParams()
// Set soft_timeout to 1000 ms
p.Add("soft_timeout", 1000u)
solver.Parameters <- p
```

See [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513944/z3-java-api-for-solver-timeout) for more information.

I don't know why you need to set `model_completion` (notice typos in your `MODEL_COMPLETITION` setting). You can always use:

```
model.Eval(expr, true)
```

where `expr` is an abitrary `Expr` and `true` means Z3 will fill in unassigned variables.

Comment: This indeed solves the problem. The project was recently "ported" from bindings to an old z3 version to 4.3 by just replacing the loaded DLL and then fixing type errors, so there is some weird stuff in there. The completion typo was introduced when I submitted the question, as I noticed the problem without a net connection and had to transport things over manually. (And yes, we always need values for all variables, because we use the models to synthesise stuff)

Comment: However, I do wonder why this problem does not show up when running the same version of the code under Windows. Not really important, I'm just surprised :-)

Comment: @mmjb: I would expect that `model_completion` can be set on `Solver` as well. I don't know why .NET version doesn't show any warning. Probably the native C++ code behind behaves differently on Linux compared to Windows.