# Unknown parameter `timeout` in `Z3_set_param_value(cfg, "timeout", "10")`;

Tags: c, api, z3

Setting timeout is always a hot topic, and there are many related answers, however, a new warning shows up in the latest unstable-branch of Z3 (4.4.2) (Ubuntu-12.04-64).

Pure C API is used in my project, I use `Z3_assert_cnstr()` to add a constraint, and `Z3_check_and_get_model()` to check result.

I set the timeout with:

`Z3_set_param_value(cfg, "timeout", "10");`

with 10 milliseconds.

When I run the project, there is a warning like:

```
WARNING: unknown parameter 'timeout'
Legal parameters are:
auto_config (bool) (default: true)
debug_ref_count (bool) (default: false)
dump_models (bool) (default: false)
model (bool) (default: true)
model_validate (bool) (default: false)
proof (bool) (default: false)
rlimit (unsigned int) (default: 4294967295)
smtlib2_compliant (bool) (default: false)
timeout (unsigned int) (default: 4294967295)
trace (bool) (default: false)
trace_file_name (string) (default: z3.log)
type_check (bool) (default: true)
unsat_core (bool) (default: false)
well_sorted_check (bool) (default: false)
```

and from the specification, "timeout" is a legal parameter.

Is there something I missed?

I tested using "10u" instead of "10" as the third parameter to indicate a unsigned number, however, nothing is changed. Besides, an ASSERTION VIOLATION fixed from master branch is the reason for me to use unstable-branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking [HERE](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/code/classcontext__params.html#a5f5b04563f23bdbb34a9bd0d28c03e4b) at the source code, I think there is a bug in

```
void set    (   char const *    param,
                char const *    value 
            )
```

The `if` below

```
if (p == "rlimit")
```

should be

```
else if (p == "rlimit")
```

to avoid the wrong error.

Looking [HERE](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/cmd_context/context_params.cpp) at the current commit on GitHub, it was corrected on Oct 7.

Comment: Thanks, @LPs, that is exact the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, @LPS. However, there is another question to ask if you known, the configuration of timeout seems  not to work. In an example, I set timeout as "1u", (1 millisecond), add some constraints (seems failure with "1u" millisecond) and wait an unknown result, however, it gets a sat result with 68.7 second, which is got from count the time difference between before  `Z3_check_and_get_model()` and after `Z3_check_and_get_model()`.

Comment: @user2940648 I'm not an Z3 expert. I found [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833925/z3-c-api-changing-timeout-at-runtime). Maybe could help.

Comment: @ LPs, I known this page,  but it is not the same with my. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In your question you refer to the unstable branch of Z3. This branch is not used anymore and has been removed from GitHub. All new development goes directly into the master branch, so definitely switch over to that before you continue.